# How to deal with a rifle scope where the relief is too short?

Tags: hunting, shooting, rifles

When a rifle has a scope where the relief is too short for comfortable shooting, are there any options other than replacing the scope? The scope has a adjustable relief, but even with that I have to push my head too far forward to see the full view.

Comment: You mean the that to acquire a proper sight picture you have to put your eye too close to the eyepiece?

Comment: It's not that it's too close, it's that my next is straining forward, such that I'm no longer fully relaxed while I shoot. It's resolved now, as far as I'm concerned. I was able to move the scope back a little by tinkering with the mounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options are available to you depending on what style rifle, scope, and rings you are using:

1. Loosen the scope rings and slide the scope along the scope tube rearward (towards the stock)
2. Move the entire scope and mounting rings rearward.  This would be the preferable option if your rifle has a picatinny style mounting rail.

Some other items to remember:

- eye relief should be set close to its forward limit (so all the way
  back is not best, do a google images search for "scope bite" if you
  would like a graphic illustration as to why)
- heavy clothing over your shoulder can effect the length of pull of
  the rifle by moving the scope forward (account for this by wearing
  the heaviest clothing you are likely to use)
- if the scope is of variable power set it to the maximum magnification (the highest power setting will give the shortest eye relief)

Comment: It's a Simmons 44 Mag; I've applied 1 & 2 to the extent that the huge bell and rings will allow. Good answer, though.